# Trigonometric integral (arctg)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a problem with this integral.
$$\int \text{arctan}(x-2)dx =\text{ }?$$
I tried integration by parts but it doesn't lead to right result.

Comment: Is the integral of $\;(x-2)\arctan x\;$ or of $\;\arctan(x(x-2))\;$ ? You should make sure your expressions in mathematics are cyrstal clear.

Comment: @davoid: In either case i.b.p. is a good strategy. Perhaps you could describe your attempt to apply it and point out where it goes wrong?

Comment: What did you get? If you show your work, we can be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the manipulations simpler we first substitute $x-2=u$ and this means $du=dv$ and we are left with $$\int\arctan{(x-2)}dx=\int\arctan{u}du$$
Now we integrate by parts $v=\arctan{u}$ and $du$. This yields $dv=\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$ and $u$. We have therefore
$$\int\arctan{u}du=u\arctan{u}-\int\frac{u}{u^2+1}du$$ and with a substitution $w=u^2+1$ we are done